# Error: Unknown .NET Framework bitness specified in 3.5

Tags: .net, frameworks

We have created an installer with powershell.
Since some days whenever I am trying to install the packages it gives me error stating:

```
default.ps1:Error: Unknown .NET Framework bitness, , specified in 3.5
```

Check the image attached: 
http://i50.tinypic.com/k04ljo.jpg

Can anyone tell whats the problem & how to resolve the same.

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using PowerUp library for running this script, this is a reported bug that was fixed, all you need is to update the file /core/psake/psake.psm1 to fix this bug reported here:
https://github.com/psake/psake/commit/4710debb0128d0bd39ff54115bc9c2872762831a

As you can see in the link, it's a one-line fix changing the check for NULL to EmptyOrNull when determining the bitness of the framework. That should do the trick.

Comment: Just passing through to mention that PowerUp will be updated within the next day with the newest version of psake. Visit https://github.com/AffinityID/PowerUp to get the update

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the environment in which you are installing in terms of x64,x86. Check if you are installer binaries have a mismatch with the current "bitness", that is if the OS is 64 bit or 32 bit

Comment: Can you show us the source of the powershell installer script? Particularly the places where you are detecting the .NET version